# Mapstruct mapper using mockito returning null object inspite being mocked

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit5, mapstruct

I have a mapper which converts one type to another type. I am writing a unit test forbusiness (service layer) where I am autowiring mapper. In the corresponding Junit of service class I am mocking mapper using Mock annotation. While debugging I could see that mapper is getting mocked but after debugging goes to service layer the mocked mapper method is returning null object

Mapper class

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface EmployeeHolidayMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "employeeEntity.empId",source = "employeeHolidayDto.empId")
    @Mapping(target = "leaveStartDate",expression = "java(LocalDate.parse(employeeHolidayDto"
            + ".getEmpLeaveStartDate().toString(),dateTimeFormatter))")
    @Mapping(target = "leaveEndDate",expression = "java(LocalDate.parse(employeeHolidayDto"
            + ".getEmpLeaveEndDate().toString(),dateTimeFormatter))")
    public EmployeeHolidayEntity employeeHoliDayDtoToEmployeeHolidayEntity(EmployeeHolidayDto 
            employeeHolidayDto,LocalDate localDate,DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter);
```

Service class

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EmployeeHolidayService {

    
    private final HolidayRepo holidayRepo;
    
    private final EmployeeHolidayRepo employeeHolidayRepo;
    
    private final EmployeeHolidayMapper employeeHolidayMapper;
    

    public Mono<Integer> saveEmployeeHolidayData(EmployeeHolidayDto employeeHolidayDto){
        return  Optional.ofNullable(employeeHolidayDto)
        .filter(dto->dto.getEmpLeaveEndDate()!=null && dto.getEmpLeaveStartDate() != null 
           && dto.getEmpLeaveStartDate() > 0 && dto.getEmpLeaveEndDate() > 0 && dto.getEmpLeaveEndDate()
           .compareTo(dto.getEmpLeaveStartDate()) >=0)
        .map(dto->{
                EmployeeHolidayEntity employeeHolidayEntity = employeeHolidayMapper
                        .employeeHoliDayDtoToEmployeeHolidayEntity(dto, LocalDate.now(),
                                DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);
                int diffOfDays = employeeHolidayEntity.getLeaveEndDate().getDayOfYear()
                        - employeeHolidayEntity.getLeaveStartDate().getDayOfYear();
                int noOfLeavesLeft = holidayRepo.getNoofLeavesLeft(dto.getEmpId()) - (diffOfDays);
                if (noOfLeavesLeft > 0) {
                    int updatedRows = holidayRepo.updateNoLeaveDays(dto.getEmpId(), noOfLeavesLeft);
                    if (updatedRows > 0) {
                        EmployeeHolidayEntity employeeHolidayEntitySaved = employeeHolidayRepo
                                .saveAndFlush(employeeHolidayEntity);
                        if (employeeHolidayEntitySaved.getEmployeeHolidayId() > 0) {
                            return Mono.just(updatedRows);
                        } else {
                            return Mono.just(0);
                        }
                    } else {
                        return Mono.just(0);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    return Mono.just(0);
                }
            
        })
        .orElse(null);
    }
```

Junit class using mockito

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class HolidaymanagementApplicationTests {

    @Mock
    HolidayRepo holidayRepo;

    @Mock
    EmployeeHolidayRepo employeeHolidayRepo;

    @Mock
    EmployeeHolidayMapper employeeHolidayMapper;

    @InjectMocks
    EmployeeHolidayService employeeHolidayService;

    @Test
    void testPostrequest() {
        String startDate = LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);
        String endDate = LocalDate.now().plusDays(2).format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);
        EmployeeHolidayDto employeeHolidayDto = new EmployeeHolidayDto(1, Integer.parseInt(startDate),
                Integer.parseInt(endDate));
        EmployeeEntity employeeEntity = new EmployeeEntity(1, null, null, null, null);
        EmployeeHolidayEntity employeeHolidayEntity = new EmployeeHolidayEntity(1,
                LocalDate.parse(startDate, DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE),
                LocalDate.parse(endDate, DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE), employeeEntity);
        when(employeeHolidayMapper.employeeHoliDayDtoToEmployeeHolidayEntity(employeeHolidayDto, LocalDate.now(),
                DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE)).thenReturn(employeeHolidayEntity);
        HolidayEntity holidayEntity = new HolidayEntity(1, 10, employeeEntity);
        when(holidayRepo.getNoofLeavesLeft(1)).thenReturn(10);
        when(holidayRepo.updateNoLeaveDays(1, 8)).thenReturn(1);
        EmployeeHolidayEntity employeeHolidayDbEntity = new EmployeeHolidayEntity(1,
                employeeHolidayEntity.getLeaveStartDate(), employeeHolidayEntity.getLeaveEndDate(), employeeEntity);
        when(employeeHolidayRepo.saveAndFlush(employeeHolidayEntity)).thenReturn(employeeHolidayDbEntity);
        assertEquals(employeeHolidayService.saveEmployeeHolidayData(employeeHolidayDto).block(), 
                1);
```

In the above code while debugging I could see that mapper is mocked. Now when implementation goes to service class from asserEquals statement. The EmployeeHolidayEntity object fetched through mapper is returning null.

When running code a spring boot application mapper is working fine and is returning the object.

Below is my entity class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "empl_holiday_tbl")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class EmployeeHolidayEntity implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2429371741034836686L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT")
    private Integer employeeHolidayId;
    
    @Column(name = "startDate", columnDefinition = "DATE NOT NULL")
    private LocalDate leaveStartDate;
    
    @Column(name = "endDate", columnDefinition = "DATE NOT NULL")
    private LocalDate leaveEndDate;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "empId",nullable = false,columnDefinition = "INT UNSIGNED")
    private EmployeeEntity employeeEntity;

}
```

Comment: `EmployeeHolidayEntity` has (meaningful) `equals` (and `hashCode`) method? (*Important* point, you didn't mention;) ..it is needed "to match mock argument (instance)s" and "not bad" for business

Comment: @xerx593 I have copied my EmployeeHolidayEntity class and it already had equals and hashcode but then also it returned null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your mock `when(` never matches the execution.

```
 when(employeeHolidayMapper.employeeHoliDayDtoToEmployeeHolidayEntity(employeeHolidayDto, LocalDate.now(),
            DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE)).thenReturn(employeeHolidayEntity);
```

contains a "LocalDate.now()" your actuall execution is a few milisenconds later. It will therefore be different and the `when(` never is used. The fallback of a mocked class is to return null which is your result.

To verify my suspicion you could try to change your code to

```
when(employeeHolidayMapper.employeeHoliDayDtoToEmployeeHolidayEntity(any(), any(),
            any())).thenReturn(employeeHolidayEntity);
```

your return value should now be correct.

Furthermore i would suggest changing your test setup. For Mockito tests with Mapstruct I usually use

```
@Spy
EmployeeHolidayMapper employeeHolidayMapper = Mappers.get(EmployeeHolidayMapper .class);

@InjectMocks
EmployeeHolidayService employeeHolidayService;
```

this way you get the real mapper since mapping is something that usually dont need mocking. You then don´t have to call `when(` on mappers in your tests.

Comment: Apologies for late reply. Many thanks for your reply and it is working. Just wanted to confirm that for LocalDate it was working as there is no time entity involved for LocalDateTime it was not working and as you suggested it was because of time not matching  while mocking and actual execution of method. Many thanks again for your wonderful answer (y)